# How do I get a Google Api OAuth 2 refresh token for my asp.net web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, google-api, youtube-api

I am trying to use OAuth 2 in my Asp.net app (C#).  The problem is I need to use a shared google account.  To do this, my plan is to seed the authentication with a token, an expiration date, and a refresh token, and then when authentication is required I check the expiration date and use the refresh token.

The example I've been using for Authentication looks like this:

```
    UserCredential credential;
    using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
            // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
            new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None
        );
    }
```

And doesn't seem to contain an object with a refresh token.

How do I get the Refresh token and expiration date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to do a post action and parse the results manually instead of using any of the Google classes.

```
        string gurl = "code=" + code + "&client_id=" + client_id +
                "&client_secret=" + client_secret + "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri + "&grant_type=" + grant_type;

        string url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token";

        // creates the post data for the POST request
        string postData = (gurl);

        // create the POST request
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Host ="www.googleapis.com";

        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.ContentLength = postData.Length;

        // POST the data
        using (StreamWriter requestWriter2 = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            requestWriter2.Write(postData);
        }

        //This actually does the request and gets the response back
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

        string googleAuth;

        using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
        {
            //dumps the HTML from the response into a string variable
            googleAuth = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

From there I mainly need to parse the googleAuth string to get at the Token, the Refresh Token, and the expiration period.  I kept expecting there to be a solution inside the Google classes for what must be an incredibly common request, but apparently I'll be creating my own class.

Comment: should I store this access_token? bcz each it will generate new access_token.